# Need to create String for Current user UID but keep getting error ('Future<String> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

This is my homepage widget...

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(''),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () => _signOut(context),
            child: Text('Sign out'),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(    ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have a Firebase collection named "users", inside it has documents, those documents are created using the signed in/registered users UID, such as "Dn0dXfzwhjWZRKYqO8N1VrUIzNm2", and in those documents contain a field: "firstname"....

I want to use a Streambuilder (in the body of my scaffold) like this:

```
StreamBuilder(
                stream: Firestore
.instance.collection('users')
.document('Dn0dXfzwhjWZRKYqO8N1VrUIzNm2')
.snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading...");
                  return _buildFirstname(context, snapshot.data);
                })
```

but, instead of having 'Dn0dXfzwhjWZRKYqO8N1VrUIzNm2' as the "document" I want it to be a string that dynamically calls the users UID, but it just won't work....

I've read all the answers from people so far, but I can't figure out what I supposed to do with the information provided because it's not clear enough for me...

PS: the widget "_buildFirstname" Is going to be a simple like this

```
Widget _buildFirstname(
      BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
    return 
        Text(document['firstname'],

    );
  }
```

By the way, my app is based on this video.

Just like in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxu4bMpPvCQ

HUGE thanks to anyone who can help me understand this. I think I need someone to explain the answer in much more detail.

I really need to understand this so I can progress.

Comment: Please do not link to external locations for people to examine your code.  Add all the relevant code into the question itself so that it can remain relevant to others even if your repo goes away.

Comment: use **final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();** to get current user

Comment: Hi guys, I'm not sure this code is working for me, can you please review my updated question and see if you can figure it out? Maybe I'm using a weird method or something...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```dart
///this variable will use in StreamBuilder

String userId = "";

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();

    ///get current user and assign his id 
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((FirebaseUser user){
        setState(() {
           userId = user.uid; 
        });
    });

}
```

in your **StreamBuilder** *(maybe you need to check if userId is null or not)*

```
StreamBuilder(
                stream: Firestore
.instance.collection('users')
.document(userId)
.snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading...");
                  return _buildFirstname(context, snapshot.data);
                })
```

Comment: Hi mate, I'm not sure this code is working for me, can you please review my updated question and see if you can figure it out? Maybe I'm using a weird method or something...

Comment: I made some changes. You need to get current firebase user in **initState**

Comment: Hi mate,

I converted my Widget to Stateful and added the code you have suggest, but now all I get returned is "Loading..."

It still thinks userId = null; but this time because it has been provided by this string  (String = userId ' ')


I give up...

Comment: Don't give up. Can you share your repo?

Comment: I haven't given up but seriously frustrated. I can't see what I'm doing wrong..

I've just decided to buy a Udemy course and brush up on the basics... I rushed into Flutter after 15 years of not coding anything and only a little experience in HTML, PHP, and ActionScript...

I've recently managed to get my call on the String to say "null". Not sure why, not sure it's broke, but I think I've got the method down, but there's something wrong with the timing in the code maybe?

This is the latest version... I'm closing it again, for now.
https://github.com/carman247/login_register_new

Comment: sorry for the late. You may need to setState like the answer. However, your initState method should be changed like this. https://github.com/ShalikaAshan01/Answer/blob/master/lib/home_page.dart